# correct the indentation error for a code segment in vscode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

While using vscode for developing python program, I directly copied one segment python code into vscode, the indentation is not right, please see the following screenshot. Besides manually correcting this code segment, how to correct the indentation automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've pasted it when there were tabs already available in the editor.

You could always use the auto indent option ( Ctrl + Shift + F ), but I don't think it would be correct.

You could use the shortcuts : `Ctrl + [` or `Ctrl + ]` to adjust the indents without worrying about whether the indent is made up of spaces or tabs.

This shortcuts works with entire blocks of code as well, you can select a chunk of code and adjust alignment that way.

Comment: I tried ctrl + I, it does not work. At first, it seems that editor does not responds to my typing. I juse use "i" in Vi to enter the edit mode, it can respond. But crtl +[ still doet not work.

Comment: your question says that you are using the vscode editor, the shortcuts i mentioned are only applicable for VScode. You may need to use other shortcuts/ commands on the VI editor, let "set ai" ( auto indent ) etc.